Four 1st order IVP ODE by Runge-Kutta 4th order scheme in C getting damped
I am currently working on a simulation project involving a two-degree-of-freedom (2DOF) airfoil. The motion of this airfoil is governed by the following equations of motion:

To numerically solve these equations, I have chosen the Runge-Kutta method due to its accuracy and stability for solving ordinary differential equations. However, I am encountering some difficulties in implementing this method for my specific problem.
My simulation is getting damped for some reason. I think it might have something to do with the runge  kutta code but I cant find any mistake.
#include "udf.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

#define PI 3.141592654

static real x1_0 = 0; //  y, heaving displacement
static real x2_0 = 0; //  y_dot, heaving velocity
static real x3_0 = 0;//-15*PI/180; //  theta, pitching displacement
static real x4_0 = 30*PI/180; //  theta_dot, pitching velocity
static real x5_0 = 0; //  V, Voltage

//static real current_time = -1;

DEFINE_CG_MOTION(flappingLinear1,dt,vel,omega,time,dtime)
{


//  real ctime = RP_Get_Real("flow-time");
//  real ctimestep = RP_Get_Integer("time-step");
//
//  if (current_time < ctimestep)
//    {
//      current_time = ctimestep;
      Thread *t;
      Domain *d;
      FILE *fp;

      real cg[3];
      real force[3]; 
      real moment[3];

      // Variables

      real S_star = -0.04;
      real Ured = 5.0;
      real eta_h = 0.1;
      real eta_theta = 0.1;
      real alpha = 0; //heaving nonlinear damping coefficient, zero if linear
      real beta = 0;  //pitching nonlinear damping coefficient, zero if linear
      real freq_h = 1/Ured;
      real freq_dash = 1.0;
      real m_star = 2.0;
      real r_theta_sq = 0.2;
      
      real theta_L = 0.00155; // 1.55E-3 V/N
      real m_h = 12.387;
      real Cap = 0.00000012; // 120 nF
      real Resis = 100000; // 100 K-Ohm

      real sigma_1 = pow(theta_L,2)/(m_h*Cap*pow(freq_h,2));
      real sigma_2 = 1/(Resis*Cap*freq_h);

      real k_theta3 = 0; // pitching nonlinear stiffness coefficient, zero if linear
      real k_h3 = 0; // pitching nonlinear stiffness coefficient, zero if linear

      real A11 = S_star;
      real A12 = pow(2*PI/Ured,2);
      real A13 = 4*PI*eta_h/Ured;
      real A14 = 4*PI*alpha*pow(freq_h,2)*Ured;
      real A15 = 2/(PI*m_star);

      real B11 = S_star/r_theta_sq;
      real B12 = pow(2*freq_dash*PI/Ured,2);
      real B13 = 4*eta_theta*freq_dash*PI/Ured;
      real B14 = 4*PI*beta*freq_dash*pow(freq_dash,2)*Ured;
      real B15 = 2/(PI*r_theta_sq*m_star);

      real D = 1 - A11*B11*pow(cos(x3_0),2);
      real D1 = 1 - A11*B11;

      real cRv = 1/pow(Ured,2);


      t = DT_THREAD(dt);
      d = Get_Domain(1);
      
      Compute_Force_And_Moment(d,t,cg,force,moment,TRUE);

      real Coeff_L = 2 * force[1];
      real Coeff_D = 2 * force[0];
      real Coeff_M = 2 * moment[2];

      #define a(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) x2 //x1_dot
      #define b(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) (1/D) * (A15*Coeff_L - A11*pow(x4_0,2)*sin(x3_0) \
                                + (A11*cos(x3_0) * (B15*Coeff_M - B12*(x3_0 + k_theta3*pow(x3_0,3)) \
                                - B13*x4_0 - B14*pow(x4_0,3))) - A12*(x1_0 + k_h3*pow(x1_0,3)) - A13*x2_0 \
                                - A14*pow(x2_0,3) + cRv*x5_0)
      #define c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) x4 //x3_dot
      #define d(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) (1/D) * (B15*Coeff_M + (B11*cos(x3_0) * (A15*Coeff_L - A12*(x1_0 + k_h3*pow(x1_0,3)) \
                                - A13*x2_0 - A14*pow(x2_0,3))) - B12*(x3_0 + k_theta3*pow(x3_0,3)) - B13*x4_0 \
                                - B14*pow(x4_0,3) + cRv*x5_0)
      #define e(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) -(sigma_1*x2_0) - (sigma_2*x5_0/Ured) //x5_dot

      // Declaring all the used variables
      double k1, l1, m1, n1, o1,
             k2, l2, m2, n2, o2,
             k3, l3, m3, n3, o3,
             k4, l4, m4, n4, o4,
             k, l, m, n, o,
             x1, x2, x3, x4, x5;

        k1 = dtime * (a(x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0, x5_0));
        l1 = dtime * (b(x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0, x5_0));
        m1 = dtime * (c(x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0, x5_0));
        n1 = dtime * (d(x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0, x5_0));
        o1 = dtime * (e(x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0, x5_0));


        k2 = dtime * (a((x1_0 + k1 / 2), (x2_0 + l1 / 2),(x3_0 + m1 / 2),(x4_0 + n1 / 2),(x5_0 + o1 / 2)));
        l2 = dtime * (b((x1_0 + k1 / 2), (x2_0 + l1 / 2),(x3_0 + m1 / 2),(x4_0 + n1 / 2),(x5_0 + o1 / 2)));
        m2 = dtime * (c((x1_0 + k1 / 2), (x2_0 + l1 / 2),(x3_0 + m1 / 2),(x4_0 + n1 / 2),(x5_0 + o1 / 2)));
        n2 = dtime * (d((x1_0 + k1 / 2), (x2_0 + l1 / 2),(x3_0 + m1 / 2),(x4_0 + n1 / 2),(x5_0 + o1 / 2)));
        o2 = dtime * (e((x1_0 + k1 / 2), (x2_0 + l1 / 2),(x3_0 + m1 / 2),(x4_0 + n1 / 2),(x5_0 + o1 / 2)));

        k3 = dtime * (a((x1_0 + k2 / 2), (x2_0 + l2 / 2),(x3_0 + m2 / 2),(x4_0 + n2 / 2),(x5_0 + o2 / 2)));
        l3 = dtime * (b((x1_0 + k2 / 2), (x2_0 + l2 / 2),(x3_0 + m2 / 2),(x4_0 + n2 / 2),(x5_0 + o2 / 2)));
        m3 = dtime * (c((x1_0 + k2 / 2), (x2_0 + l2 / 2),(x3_0 + m2 / 2),(x4_0 + n2 / 2),(x5_0 + o2 / 2)));
        n3 = dtime * (d((x1_0 + k2 / 2), (x2_0 + l2 / 2),(x3_0 + m2 / 2),(x4_0 + n2 / 2),(x5_0 + o2 / 2)));
        o3 = dtime * (e((x1_0 + k2 / 2), (x2_0 + l2 / 2),(x3_0 + m2 / 2),(x4_0 + n2 / 2),(x5_0 + o2 / 2)));

        k4 = dtime * (a((x1_0 + k3), (x2_0 + l3),(x3_0 + m3),(x4_0 + n3),(x5_0 + o3)));
        l4 = dtime * (b((x1_0 + k3), (x2_0 + l3),(x3_0 + m3),(x4_0 + n3),(x5_0 + o3)));
        m4 = dtime * (c((x1_0 + k3), (x2_0 + l3),(x3_0 + m3),(x4_0 + n3),(x5_0 + o3)));
        n4 = dtime * (d((x1_0 + k3), (x2_0 + l3),(x3_0 + m3),(x4_0 + n3),(x5_0 + o3)));
        o4 = dtime * (d((x1_0 + k3), (x2_0 + l3),(x3_0 + m3),(x4_0 + n3),(x5_0 + o3)));

        k = (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6;
        l = (l1 + 2 * l2 + 2 * l3 + l4) / 6;
        m = (m1 + 2 * m2 + 2 * m3 + m4) / 6;
        n = (n1 + 2 * n2 + 2 * n3 + n4) / 6;
        o = (o1 + 2 * o2 + 2 * o3 + o4) / 6;

        x1 = x1_0 + k;
        x2 = x2_0 + l;
        x3 = x3_0 + m;
        x4 = x4_0 + n;
        x5 = x5_0 + o;

        //updating values
        x1_0 = x1;
        x2_0 = x2;
        x3_0 = x3;
        x4_0 = x4;
        x5_0 = x5;

        vel[1] = x2;
        omega[2] = x4;

        //radian to degree
        real pitch_angle = x3*57.3;


        #if RP_HOST
        fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fp, "%.5f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f %.10f\n", 
          time, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, Coeff_L, Coeff_D, Coeff_M, pitch_angle);
        fclose(fp);
        #endif
//      }
//
//  vel[1] = x2_0;
//  omega[2] = x4_0;

}

DEFINE_CG_MOTION(FLBoundary1,dt,vel,omega,time,dtime)
{
  vel[1] = x2_0;
  omega[2] = x4_0;
}

The solution should look like this:

but the it comes out to be like:

Can someone have a look at my code and point out any error in the Runge-Kutta Code?

Why do you use the _0 variables in a,c,e? Better make these macros into proper functions. This would catch this scoping error. Leave the inlining to the compiler.

I appreciate your response. I mainly work on CFD, and programming is not my strong suit. Could you elaborate on what changes I should make?

As a first step, remove in #define b, d and e (not a and c, i had that wrong) the _0 subscripts from the variables. This should get the RK4 method correct. Then or in future avoid using macros for function definitions. Macros work by text replacement, with no syntax or grammar check before. This easily leads to hard-to-detect errors.
